# Add control panel to any Chrome page using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When Chrome is being automated with Selenium/Puppeteer, we see a panel at the top of the page that says:

> chrome is being controlled by automated test software

My question is - is there a way to add a panel like this to any Chrome page, using a Chrome Extension? I want to add controls on any page that have to do with my Chrome Extension, but I don't want to interfere with the page itself, if I can avoid it.

In other words, I don't want to inject JS into the user's page, I want to add some panel to Chrome or to Chrome Dev Tools.

I am looking to add a panel that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to be able to add some controls (buttons / event-handlers) to the panel if possible!

Comment: Looks like I can add a panel to Chrome Dev Tools - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels, but I want to find out if I can add a panel to Chrome without having to open DevTools.

Comment: selenium uses [infobar](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/infobars) to display this text, but this api is deprecated and you can't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only way without js would be to inject a custom css style like this:

```css
body:before
{
  content:"You are being watched...";
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: antiquewhite;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: cool is it possible to add HTML and JS to this? I would want to add buttons and event handlers

Comment: I added a screenshot - I'd really like to be able to add a panel like that, and add some buttons to it

Comment: But I thought you didn't want to inject js... You have to decide between these options. Actually most other extensions do inject js if they need to display something on the page. (so do I)

Comment: in the screenshot in the OP, the tan colored infobar is not part of the HTML on the page, it's actually part of the Chrome application itself. it's created using the API at `window.chrome.infobars`, but that's deprecated.

Comment: the nice thing about infobars, is it won't interfere at all with the HTML page, obviously, given what I said